# Apache Pulsar maximum supported message size

Tags: stream, message-queue, apache-pulsar

What is the maximum message size supported by Apache Pulsar?

I tried reading the documentation. But I couldn't find any relevant information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default max message size is 5242880 bytes (5 MiB), but it can be adjusted. See this Wiki page for details:

https://github.com/apache/pulsar/wiki/PIP-36%3A-Max-Message-Size